# How to get user details from svn?

Tags: svn, slik

How can I retrieve details for a user (like their name and email) from their username from `svn`? I am using `SlikSVN`, which is a command line client.

Comment: You could use AD integration which has all the information you put into user's profiles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nohow.

SVN's revision property contain only username and SVN per se doesn't store any additional metadata about user

Comment: well, that's kinda lame but it's the way it is.  especially in repos used by many developers.  but i wish it was the only problem in svn...

Comment: @amphibient - you can store any data in authorization-backend's database